# replace dot "." by comma "," after title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I've just turned to `biblatex` from `bibtex`. Below is my option for `biblatex`

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true,backend=biber, maxcitenames=3,%
            maxbibnames=9, sortcites, url=false, backref=false,]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{proposal.bib}
\usepackage{babel} % Switch to English style quotation mark, remember to add british to document option
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace} % Remove dot in the bibliography after Author(year)

\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % Suppress In: in the reference list

%use ":" after year in the in-text citation
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

%format pages in the article entry of bibliography 
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace} {\addcomma\addspace}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}

%format volume và issue

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

Here is the example of @article entry:

```
@Article{Vanschoenwinkel2016,
  author  = {Vanschoenwinkel, Janka and Mendelsohn, Robert and Van Passel, Steven},
  title   = {Do Western and Eastern Europe have the same agricultural climate response? Taking adaptive capacity into account},
  journal = {Global Environmental Change},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {74-87},
  issn    = {0959-3780},
  type    = {Journal Article},
}
```

if follow above setup, the format of an article entry in the Bibliography would be:

> Vanschoenwinkel, J., R. Mendelsohn and S. Van Passel (2016) ‘Do
>   Western and Eastern Europe 
>       have the same agricultural climate response? Taking adaptive capacity into account’**.**
>       *Global Environmental Change* 41 (7): 74-87.

How can I replace the dot  "." after the title by comma ","?

Comment: Your braces in `\bibpagespunct` are off, it should probably be `\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace}{\addcomma\addspace}}` or `\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma}\addspace}`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Probably  there is a missing of "}" in the code above, but I did double check the code in my tex file as your suggestion. Probably due to typo. I did revise the code above.

Comment: Please always check that the code you post as example works the way you think it does. That's why we encourage users to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/) - complete, yet small document that can be copied, pasted and run without further modifications. MWEs make it easier to answer your questions because there is something to get started from. Plus they make sure we are all talking about the same thing: Fewer things are more frustrating than misunderstandings because you use actually use code different from the one shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that this is the *only* punctuation change in the bibliography, there isn't a built in way of doing this.

But you can use the `xpatch` package to patch each bibliography driver to change the punctuation of the title from a period to a comma. e.g., to change it for article entry types, you'd add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {}
```

I use `\printunit` rather than `\setunit` to ensure that a comma persists in the punctuation buffer, rather than being overwritten by subsequent `\newunit` commands.

You could do something similar for other entry types. Have a look at the file `standard.bbx` to see how titles are printed for other entry types as it varies slightly.

**Aside**, your question was down voted (probably) because your code does not compile. There's a missing brace and it doesn't start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. In the future, include a MWE like mine below.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Vanschoenwinkel2016,
  author  = {Vanschoenwinkel, Janka and Mendelsohn, Robert and Van Passel,
             Steven},
  title   = {Do Western and Eastern Europe have the same agricultural climate
             response? Taking adaptive capacity into account},
  journal = {Global Environmental Change},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {74-87}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true, maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=9, sortcites, url=false, backref=false,]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace
  {\addcomma\addspace}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]